# Will a Fujifilm X-Pro1 and Jupiter 12 35mm f2.8 lens work together with a Tarion Camera Adapter Ring?

Tags: lens-adapter, old-lenses, fujifilm, fujifilm-xpro1

I own a Fujifilm X-Pro1 camera and I have used it together with a jupiter 8 lens. To mount it I use the "TARION" camera adaptor ring and this set up works for me.

Now I would like to get more width and I have ordered a Jupiter 12 35mm f2.8 lens.
I read comments on forums that there might be an issue with the Jupiter 12 lens on the Fujifilm X-Pro1 camera body. The comments suggest that the jupiter 12 lens doesn´t fit properly and it would touch the sensor.
Can you use the Jupiter 12 lens with a Fujifilm X-Pro1 body? Can anyone share some wisdom whether this set up works well?

Comment: Can someone tag the question with "jupiter-12"?
I don´t have enough rep.

Comment: "jupiter-12" seems like maybe a little more specific than we need a tag for, but I made [tag:jupiter]. I guess we could do the specific lens if others think it'd be useful.

Comment: This is likely the only question we'll ever have that needs a "Jupiter 12" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using the Jupiter 8 on a camera with a cropped sensor isn't that the back of the lens will touch the sensor. The adapter ring, such as your "Tarion", insures that the rear of the lens will remain in front of the sensor since it establishes a registration distance for which the lens was designed. The problem is that the rear of the lens is too large to fit into the recessed alcove that surrounds most cropped sensors, including the sensor for your X-Pro1. Notice in the photo below that the rectangular cutout the same size as the recessed sensor is very close to the lens mounting flange. If the Jupiter 12 extends that deeply past the rear of the camera-side flange of the Tarion adapter (and it does when focused at certain distances) then it won't fit into the light box of the camera.

Post #3 at [this thread](http://www.fujix-forum.com/threads/jupiter-12-35mm-2-8-experience.51477/) on the Fuji X forum bears this out.

[image: Fuji X-Pro1]